# How to verify LeakCanary is working properly - We cannot see LeakCanary in logging

Tags: android, leakcanary

I have a legacy project which

- In Java
- Have not migrate to AndroidX

Recently, it is having mystery `OutOfMemoryException` in production.

We use the following in order to figure the root cause

```
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.3'
```

We also call `refWatcher = LeakCanary.install(this);` in our `Application`'s `onCreate`.

But, after we have done all the above, and run in Emulator, we filter out our Android Studio log using

> D/LeakCanary

But, we don't see any log regarding `LeakCanary`.

Is there anything we have missed out?

But, we see 0 output.

Is there anything else we had missed out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to add

```
implementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.3'
```

The only dependency required for leak canary is:

```
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.3'
```

After that add following code in your `Application` onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) {
        // This process is dedicated to LeakCanary for heap analysis.
        // You should not init your app in this process.
        return;
    }
    LeakCanary.install(this);

    // rest of your init code
}
```

After that there will be an App installed with following icon:

[image: leak canary icon]

Now you just need to run your app. When a memory leak happen a dialog will be shown that leak is detected.

When you open the app with above mentioned icon you will see memory leak with leak trace :

[image: leak-trace]

Answer (score 1):

LeakCanary library is now upgraded to 2.x version.

To use LeakCanary, add the leakcanary-android dependency to your app’s build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  // debugImplementation because LeakCanary should only run in debug builds.
  debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.4'
}
```

That’s it, there is no code change needed!

Confirm that LeakCanary is running on startup by filtering on the LeakCanary tag in Logcat:

```
D LeakCanary: LeakCanary is running and ready to detect leaks
```

Source: https://square.github.io/leakcanary/getting_started/

Comment: I tried this but the LeakCanary tag is still not showing for me.  I tried running normally and running in debug; still nothing.

Comment: @NaturallyAsh Are you able to see other logs?
If you have integrated leakcanary library then you should get the leakcanary logs in the logcat.

Comment: it's strange because it works via the Leaks app installed on the target device but for some reason it doesn't show up in the logcat. There may be something faulty on my end but I can confirm that it at least shows leaks on the device Leaks app.